# Simple Laravel SELECT statement is exhausting memory

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I've got a fairly simple select statement running in Laravel. When I run it, I get an "allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes)" error message.

When I run the query in MySQL, I get ~56k rows returned, only taking 2.0ms. I don't see why Laravel is choking on such a simple operation. What am I doing wrong? I have tried removing the group by, changing it to an order by, and removing the duplicates in PHP, but that still didn't solve the problem.

My Laravel code:

```
DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();

$connections = DB::table('some_table')
        ->whereIn('some_table.companyid',array_keys(Access::companies()))
        ->whereIn('some_table.campaignid',$map['campaigns'])
        ->whereNull('some_table.deleted_at')
        ->groupBy('some_table.employeeid')
        ->groupBy('some_table.bossid')
        ->select('id')
        ->get();
```

What the query comes out to:

```
SELECT
    `id` 
FROM 
    `some_table` 
WHERE 
    `some_table`.`companyid` in (1,4,16,18,20,40,42,70,71,88,97,105,106,107,109,115,118,119,122,128,130,131,132,135,143,147,2,5,6,14,19,21,23,29,36,37,38,39,43,44,45,46,47,52,54,56,61,62,67,68,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,86,87,89,90,92,93,94,95,96,99,100,102,103,108,110,111,112,116,120,124,125,126,127,129,136,138,140,141,144,145,146,148,149,150,154,155,3,48,49,50,84,114,142) 
    AND 
    `some_table`.`campaignid` in (110) 
    AND
    `some_table`.`deleted_at` is null 
GROUP BY `some_table`.`employeeid`, `some_table`.`bossid`
```

Comment: it's not about laravel, it's about php, you are returning many rows at once and store them into array or object, you are returned this rows in mysql, because you didn't stored them anywhere in memory.

Comment: @Umren So I'll always need to page (`->take(1000)->skip($startOn)`) results like this in Laravel? Or does Laravel offer a different solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP uses memory to perform queries as well.  So performing queries from a PHP application will indeed use more memory than performing them straight from MySQL.

I did a simple calculation and 33554432 bytes comes out to 32MB.  So I would suggest modifying your php.ini settings.  This should let you output data, and from there you can tune your SQL.

In your php.ini:

```
memory_limit=32M
```

Comment: Setting it to 64M just worked, yes. But thats just a workaround - any idea why Laravel is using up so much memory? If I ran this query using PHP's PDO class directly I don't think I would have this issue.

Comment: Try running it in pdo to find out :)

Comment: Laravel uses PDO::FETCH_CLASS by default. The default setting can be found in "app/config/database.php".

Comment: @user2797224 What does that have to do with this?